# meta Information in an external stylesheet

Tags: css

I'm looking at a stylesheet that I inherited and have to try to update.  Right at the beginning is something I've never seen before.  Here are 3 of the lines:

```
meta.foundation-version{font-family:"/5.5.3/"}
meta.foundation-mq-small{font-family:"/only screen/";width:0}
...
meta.foundation-data-attribute-namespace{font-family:false}
```

Can anyone tell me what these lines are supposed to do?

If I interpret this as normal CSS, the first one would be indicating that for meta elements with a class of "foundation-version", then the font-family should be set to /5.5.3/, but this doesn't make any sense ... why would one ever see a meta tag rendered, and that doesn't sound like a font family.  So, what is this really saying or doing?

I haven't found any documentation of this kind of CSS code.  There is some mention of "meta" in SASS, but I haven't explored SASS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I worked with Zurb Foundation once which is basically Bootstrap with or with out the ui components.

What I know from that time that meta.foundation-version and all other related values has to do something with default css variables / boilerplate / css resets and Javascript components / dependancies.

// Meta styles are included in all builds, as they are a dependancy of the Javascript.
// Used to provide media query values for javascript components.
// Forward slash placed around everything to convince PhantomJS to read the value.

Hopefully this qualify your answer.